# Android HttpURLConnection set GET Request method

Tags: android, httprequest, httpurlconnection

I would like to send HTTP Request with GET method, but I can't set the GET method.
Here's my code:

```
try {
                URL url = new URL(path);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("p1", "123")
                        .appendQueryParameter("p2", "123");
                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                conn.connect();
                Log.e("ERROR", conn.getResponseMessage());
                Log.e("ERROR", conn.getRequestMethod());
                Log.e("ERROR", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
            }
```

In the code, I set GET method, but on the log, request method is POST:

```
02-01 16:48:54.766  23799-23831/? E/ERROR﹕ Method Not Allowed
02-01 16:48:54.766  23799-23831/? E/ERROR﹕ POST
02-01 16:48:54.766  23799-23831/? E/ERROR﹕ 405
```

What is a problem?

Comment: Please show second half part of your `url`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the problem is

```
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

when set to true the request method is changed to `POST`, since GET or DELETE can't have a request body

Comment: yes, you are right! It is working with GET method now. Thanks!

Comment: Another question has came now. If I remove setDoOutput command, GET data are being sent. It's saying, method does not support a request body: GET. How can I bind the data to send?

Comment: GET doesn't support body. That's not an Android thing, is a http constraint. You should check the documentation of your webservice and check what else is available.

Comment: I got the idea, I can send the some value using header. conn.setRequestProperty("p1", "123"); It worked!